# Populating row headers with numbers till a certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to populate a worksheet's row headers by labeling them with Box numbers like:

Box 1

Box 2

Box 3

... and so on.

The number of boxes is in another sheet. If the number written there is 8, will it be possible to populate the other sheet's rows from Box 1 to Box 8?

Am I making sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you need something fancier that what you specifically asked for, you may need to resort to VBA. If not, the following works:

1. Create a new Excel File with two Sheets.
2. On 2nd worksheet, in cell A1, enter the number 10
3. On 1st worksheet, in cell A1, enter the formula:

   =IF(COLUMN()<=Sheet2!$A$1,"BOX " & COLUMN(), "")
4. On 1st Worksheet, select A1.
5. Press CTRL-SHFT-RIGHT (this will select the entire row)
6. Press CTRL-R (this will fill the formula to the right)

This works because COLUMN() returns the current column number (A1, A2, A3 all return 3. B1, B2, B3 all return 2).

A simple comparison between the value in Sheet2 and the current COLUMN() value gives the 1, 2, 3... up to whatever you entered into Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```css
Sub test()
'change the sheet names and cell address in Range() to yours
 i = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For j = 1 To i
'replace 1 with your column no in cells(j,1)
Cells(j, 1).Value = "Box " & j
Next

End Sub
```